# 2010 - Expand Collapse Column in a List

Tags: list

So my goal is to make a simple FAQs on my Sharepoint.

I made a list with 2 Columns (Question, Answer) both Multiple Line of Text and use the newsletter style.

When you look at the list you see questions and answers. I would like to hide the answers and make them OnClick visible. So the Column with the answer expands and collapses.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. You will need some additional JavaScript and CSS work to be done. You need to configure a list view web part. The list view  web part has a format called [XSLT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff606773(v=office.14).aspx).

This will have some effort to be put in. But possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view with one column: the answer column.  Then group by the Question column.  No idea how this would look, but it should work.

Comment: Good Idea, but i can't group by Questions because it is multiple line of text. When i use instead title(single line of text) instead it works...but it does not look nice because the size of the question is pretty small compared to my anwser. Anyway thank you.